# Check if PC has sufficient power for all components

Tags: power-supply

I am suspecting my PC to be running low on power, when I try to use an external hard drive (getting random I/O errors after I connect it, not all the time, only when both drives are busy). Is there any **easy** way to check if the power supply is supplying enough power for all components?

Comment: How is the external drive connected and how is it powered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB can only provide 2.5W per port. I doubt 5W is going to change your PC from being stable to random errors - if it was running that close to the edge of the PSU you'd be getting more issues. Sounds more like a dodgy caddy/controller on the external drive.

Try either testing the drive internally (take it out the box, plug it in with IDE/SATA); or a different external disk.

Answer (score 6):

[This site has a power supply calculator that should help you.](http://extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp)

You fill in all the parts your computer has and it will calculate the recommended amount of Watts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generically, try using a killawatt plug http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/travelpower/7657/

Worth their weight in gold over time.