# how to check if my power supply can handle additional components

Tags: power-supply, computer-building

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if PC has sufficient power for all components](https://superuser.com/questions/209150/check-if-pc-has-sufficient-power-for-all-components)

I built a computer last year, and have added a few new components to it since I did. When I first bought the unit, it came as a package from Newegg, so I did not worry too much about the power supply. Since I have added new components, I want to double check to make sure my PSU is not being overworked. How can I check the strain on my PSU and determine if it has enough wattage to add new components, such as extra ram, a sound card, etc?

Comment: Update your question to include all the components of your computer. You can rather simply calculate how much power you CAN be pulling by observing the TDP of your components. Other than that you would need something like, [Kill-A-Watt](http://www.p3international.com/products/special/P4400/P4400-CE.html)

Comment: @AlanTuring ... *Don't* update the question to contain the exact parts of your computer, because that would render the question as too localized, and it would likely be closed. This question, as-is, is *great* in form, though I haven't currently checked if it's a duplicate.

Comment: Its not a duplicate of this question even though the answer may be the same, but i see what you mean by being too specific. If two questions have the same answer, are they duplicates?

Comment: If two questions are similar, and have the same answer, they are considered duplicates.

Comment: @AlanTuring I'd argue that they are duplicates if they are similar questions and have the same answer, and while one should be closed, there is probably reason not to delete it if the question is worded differently, as this will help more users find the answer even if they don't think exactly like the first person when searching. If the questions are indistinguishable, then one should be deleted.

Comment: fair enough, but then there should be some procedure to refer the question to the Answer of said other question, or have that other Answer display over here. After all, someone performing a keyword search may not be looking for the same exact problem of the other "duplicate question" since it is framed in a considerably different manner.